# Why is the voltage collected by stm32adc inaccurate？

Tags: stm32

I am using the STM32F103C8T6. I use the ADC for multi-channel voltage acquisition, and a potentiometer to control the voltage change. I find that the ADC value changes fluctuate. Why?

This is part of my ADC code:

```
uint32_t ADC_Get_Average(uint8_t ch,uint8_t times)
{
    ADC_ChannelConfTypeDef sConfig;     
    uint32_t value_sum=0;   
    uint8_t i;
    switch(ch)                          
    {
        case 1:sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_1;break;   
        case 2:sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_2;break;
        case 3:sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_3;break;
    }
    sConfig.SamplingTime = ADC_SAMPLETIME_1CYCLE_5;     
    sConfig.Rank = 1;
    HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1,&sConfig);                                         
    for(i=0;i<times;i++)
    {
        HAL_ADC_Start(&hadc1);                                          
        HAL_ADC_PollForConversion(&hadc1,5);        
        value_sum += HAL_ADC_GetValue(&hadc1);                      
        HAL_ADC_Stop(&hadc1);                                           
    }
    return value_sum/times;                                             
}

void ADC_PROC(void)
{
  ADC_value1 = ADC_Get_Average(1,5) / 4096.0 * 3.3;
  ADC_value2 = ADC_Get_Average(2,5) / 4096.0 * 3.3;
  ADC_value3 = ADC_Get_Average(3,5) / 4096.0 * 3.3;
    
  sprintf(adcbuff1, "V1:%.2fV", ADC_value1);
  oled_show_string(24, 0, adcbuff1, 2);
  sprintf(adcbuff2, "V2:%.2fV", ADC_value2);
  oled_show_string(24, 2, adcbuff2, 2);
  sprintf(adcbuff3, "V3:%.2fV", ADC_value3);
  oled_show_string(24, 4, adcbuff3, 2);
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZLf6.jpg)

I have tried to change the length of ADC's acquisition cycle side, but the effect is still the same, with severe fluctuations.

Comment: A little more info about what you mean by "serious fluctuations" could help explain what is going on here. Can you provide some sample data, or just statistics about it (mean, range, etc.)? That will help narrow down the possible causes, since there are many.

Comment: ok，wait a moment please

Comment: That is, when I turn the potentiometer, the digital jitter will appear on my OLED screen, for example: 2.89v-2.56v. It keeps changing within this range, but if it is normal, it should be 2.89-2.88, but it fluctuates in a large range.

Comment: That isn't such a big range for a potentiometer, depending on the quality of the device. I see a few other problems as well: `ADC_Get_Average` returns uint32, but is divided by double-length float values. Use an explicit conversion here for better accuracy: `3.3f * (float)ADC_Get_Average(...) >> 12)`

Comment: Can you add a schematic to your question, to show us how this potentiometer is being sampled by the ADC?

Comment: oh, thank you! let me try it。

Comment: Have you determined that this jitter is a symptom of your code? Use an oscilloscope or similar to determine whether the actual voltage is jittery. If the voltage jitters it's a hardware problem and this question belongs on [electronics.se]

Comment: What is the value of your potentiometer? If your potentiometer's resistance value at the input of ADC is higher than 50kohm, you are likely get inconsistent values. You probably shouldn't use `sConfig.SamplingTime = ADC_SAMPLETIME_1CYCLE_5;` unless you had very low input impedance, all these are described in the datasheet under the ADC characteristics. If you are not sure, try use `ADC_SAMPLETIME_55CYCLES_5` see if it get better result.

Comment: I would suggest using a voltage divider, where the other resistor will be the nominal (half the maximum) value of your potentiometer. That way the reading you get will be less affected by the input impedance of your ADC. My guess is that this question belongs on Electrical Engineering, as @TangentiallyPerpendicular suggested.

Comment: I have found the problem, it is voltage jitter, belongs to the hardware problem, and thank you very much for giving me so many solutions, you are very kind

Answer (score 0):

> I find that the ADC value changes fluctuate. Why?

There are many reasons for that. First of all potentiometers are not ideal. It is normal for them to have around 10% accuracy with up to 5% noise. Additionally your power source is probably not ideal either, never producing exactly 5V. If you want to conduct a quality measurements, you should use a proper lab equipment such as DC-power supply with a high precision output.

Additionally there might be issues in your setup. Are you using a dedicated PCB or maybe a breakout board? Do you have loose cables? Are there any interference sources around? Is your ground connection as short as possible or maybe it is acting as an additional antenna?

You might want to connect an oscilloscope to the ADC input pin and see the voltage for yourself. That way you will know how much it fluctuates.

Now onto how you can fix this:

1. Measure averages (If you do this already you can increase the sample count)
2. Increase sample time (in cycles), ideally to the highest count you can, something like 500 samples. This will greatly increase the accuracy compared to the sample rate of e.g. 3 samples.
3. Improve your HW setup. Make sure all cables are as short as possible and there are no loose antennas.
4. If you feel that now it takes too long to measure all the ADCs, you might want to add DMA buffer where you can read how many samples you want at once and only calculate average when all the samples are collected.
5. If this is still not enough you might want to take a look at an STM32 that is dedicated for signal processing such as STM32F373, as they are equipped with higher quality peripherals e.g. Sigma-Delta ADC. Or you could use an external high-precision ADC module.